# Ipad orientation problem when a splitview is brought in

Tags: ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an application in which my first view has a label and a button..when I click the button, I bring in a split view.

The problem I am facing is that, the orientation of the split view is acting wierd. At times, it displays in landscape orientation properly and at other times, it displays in portrait orientation with half of its view cut. During this time, when I change the ipad orientations using the cmd + arrow keys, the split view goes haphazard.

I have included in my info.plist file -> Information property list " Initial interface orientation" and its value " landscape (right home button)". Other than that, I have not made any change...

The main thing which is bugging me is that, this does not happen all the time. It happens off and on.

It would be great if someone could help me out in this.

Comment: i am facing the same problem . Do u have the fix? PLease share with me as well. Thanks........ m waiting

Comment: nope.. I have not found a fix for it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the docs, I think it says that the split view should be the root view of the application. Not complying with this will likely cause 'buggy' behaviour.

Comment: thank you for the reply.. i just understood what you meant.. I will check it out...

Answer (score 1):

If Jack is right, you should let the split view be the root view and just display your first view above it. When the button is tapped you dismiss the first view and the root view/split view will be visible.

Comment: I finished checking my code.. I am having my root view as my split view... I dont know what else is wrong...